# DE 9926 and 9915 datasheet

Tags: transistors

Are there anyone can help me to give information about transistor DE 9926 and 9915? Could you like to share their datasheet ? I can not find their datasheet in every internet.

---

[image]
This is the transistor that I mean.

Comment: Is this an identification question? I'm not sure these even exist. What is DE supposed to mean?

Comment: can you share a photo (or a scan) of the parts

Comment: Thank you very much Jasen,I will share the foto at Google+ Stack Exchange...

Comment: Your accepted answer is WRONG!

Comment: 9926 looks like a date code. wk26 1999.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They might be [MJW16060A](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/M/J/W/1/MJW16010A-D.shtml) NPN high-voltage transistors, the packaging matches. The 9926 and 9915 are date codes most likely.

Comment: I very much agree.....

Comment: Thank you very much...this is a good information for me...

Comment: Yes, obvious Motorola logo on them... an MJW is their prefix. The older/original datasheet is at http://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view/4804/MOTOROLA/MJW16010.html

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find as DExxxx, but these may be equivalent parts from other manufacturers:

Dual N-Channel 2.5V Specified PowerTrenchÒ MOSFET
https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FD/FDS9926A.pdf

N-CHANNEL ENHANCEMENT-MODE. POWER MOSFET
http://www.siliconstandard.com/Documents/SSM9915H,J.pdf

If the descriptions don't seem to match what you have then verify that you are listing the actual transistor part number (and not a "Date Code" number on the case".

Comment: From the photo you now posted I would strongly agree with the answer given by Renan.